# File upload code not workink in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

FILE UPLOAD CODE IS NOT WORKING

i am getting this error when uploading  file  XYZ
please help me in removing null path value 
The system cannot find the path specified

```
INFO: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\XYZ.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:394)
at org.apache.jsp.UploadFile_jsp._jspService(UploadFile_jsp.java from :112)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

code for uploading are first html  code

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <form method="post" action="UploadFile.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</center>

<form class="Manage-forms" action="login.jsp" method="post">
        <button class="Manage-button" type="submit" name="edit_submit" value="hello">
            <img src="Images\Edit_icon.png" title="Update"  alt="Edit" height="25"    width="25" border=0>
        </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

then to redirecting page

```
   <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
   <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>

<%
 File file ;
 int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
 int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
 ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
 String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");

// Verify the content type
 String contentType = request.getContentType();
 if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
  factory.setRepository(new File("d:\\temp"));

  // Create a new file upload handler
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
  upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
  try{ 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

     // Process the uploaded file items
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     while ( i.hasNext () ) 
     {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
        if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
        {
        // Get the uploaded file parameters
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String fileName = fi.getName();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
        // Write the file
        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
        file = new File( filePath + 
        fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }else{
        file = new File( filePath + 
        fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;
        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + 
        fileName + "<br>");
        }
     }
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
  }catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
 }else{
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");
  }
%>
```

Comment: Maybe the clue is in the first line `null\XYZ.xls`. The path to the file is `null`.

Comment: null is not path , it is error

Comment: `null\XYZ.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)` just saying

Comment: your code saying that it cannot locate the `null` directory

Comment: Whenever you upload files only the filename is supplied. The filePath is stripped out by the browser.

Comment: this code is running in eclipse

Comment: may be `String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");` returning null, check out.

Comment: Just try to save the file to a hardcoded path which you know exists to test.